# Why does the Prettier extension automatically format some multiline code and not others?

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

apologies if this has been asked before. Relatively new to coding and just want to ensure I'm following the best practices when writing code. As recommended by a friend, I downloaded the Prettier extension to help format code. However, I found that sometimes it'll format multiline code in objects / div components, but now for all. See attached image below.

I already looked through Prettier's settings but could not find a solution. Please help. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prettier will format to a new line when you exceed 80 characters per line (it is the default option). Please refer to [this documentation](http://Lorem%20ipsum%20dolor%20sit%20amet,%20consectetur%20adipiscing%20elit.%20Nam%20vehicula%20tellus%20faucibus%20metus%20consequat%20scelerisque.%20Maecenas%20sit%20amet%20urna%20quis%20ipsum%20interdum%20consequat.%20Praesent%20elementum%20libero%20nec%20velit%20suscipit%20placerat%20accumsan%20vitae%20lacus.%20Aliquam%20erat%20volutpat.%20Etiam%20egestas%20lectus%20sed%20orci%20venenatis,%20ullamcorper%20gravida%20elit%20pulvinar.%20Pellentesque%20imperdiet,%20augue%20pulvinar%20sodales%20dapibus,%20tortor%20magna%20rutrum%20nulla,%20vel%20ullamcorper%20mi%20purus%20a%20diam.%20Ut%20id%20odio%20sed%20arcu%20aliquet%20lobortis.%20Lorem%20ipsum%20dolor%20sit%20amet,%20consectetur%20adipiscing%20elit.%20Donec%20quam%20arcu,%20egestas%20feugiat%20eleifend%20blandit,%20vulputate%20non%20elit.%20Nulla%20a%20erat%20vel%20leo%20maximus%20viverra%20at%20ac%20lorem.%20Nam%20non%20imperdiet%20lorem.%20Fusce%20tempor%20arcu%20massa,%20non%20commodo%20ligula%20lobortis%20nec.%20Aliquam%20sit%20amet%20fringilla%20sapien,%20non%20euismod%20metus.%20Donec%20orci%20mi,%20sagittis%20vitae%20lobortis%20eu,%20aliquet%20nec%20libero.%20Sed%20sodales%20magna%20lacus,%20pretium%20lobortis%20magna%20varius%20nec.%20Pellentesque%20quis%20ipsum%20viverra%20orci%20lobortis%20egestas.%20Aliquam%20porttitor%20tincidunt%20ipsum,%20egestas%20placerat%20ante%20consectetur%20in.%20Morbi%20porttitor%20lacus%20eu%20augue%20tincidunt,%20at%20aliquet%20lorem%20consectetur.) for more information.

Since you are using visual studio code, you can notice at the bottom right corner of your screen this "Col" counter.

[image: bar]

This is how many characters there are from the beginning of the line until where your cursor is currently at. I hope I helped you get a better understanding.

Comment: Yes thank you so much for the explanation and for providing the doc for reference. Exactly what I wanted.